# Can I show the count of total markers in map amcharts if there are multiple markers on same latitude and longitude?

Tags: dictionary, amcharts4

[image]

In the image above, there are few places where there are multiple markers but I cannot view it clearly. I want the counter of these markers which are on the same latitude and longitude.

Comment: hey muskan, welcome to SO. Please maintain a question standard. Make your title short to highlight and add a little more description in your question. You can visit for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: okay, @EmtiazZahid. Sorry, I have asked the first question.